# What are the files that the .dockerignore works on?

Tags: docker

I don't really understand how `.dockerignore` works.
Is it intended to be used like the following:

- First I add somethings in it such as `*.md`
- Then I put this `.dockerignore` into the container.
- After that I run and enter the container.
- I create a new file named `test.md` and commit this container to the new image.
- The new image will ignore this file so it will not be in the new container.

Answer (score 32):

Before explaining the use of the .dockerignore file we must spend a little time understanding what `docker build` does.

## Docker build. What does happen when I build an image ?

When you build an image from a Dockerfile using the `docker build` command the daemon will create a context. That context contains everything in the directory you executed the command in.

## What does .dockerignore do and why use it?

The `.dockerignore` file allows you to exclude files from the context like a .gitignore file allow you to exclude files from your git repository.

It helps to make build faster and lighter by excluding from the context big files or repository that are not used in the build.

Comment: I wonder why that context contain everything in the directory.I didn't see those files in container which is run through an image built from the the dockerfile.

Comment: If the Dockerfile requires nothing externally, can the .dockerignore contain just `*` ?

Answer (score 9):

`docker build` has a step where it `tar`s up the `CONTEXT` directory and sends it to the `docker daemon`. This is because the `daemon` and `client` might not exist on the same server.

The `tar` and network send is why unused files can slow down the build. These happen even if the `daemon` runs locally.

Comment: this definitely makes better sense than the top answer

Answer (score 1):

> Then I put this .dockerignore in container.

nope, don't do that. The `.dockerignore` file is meant to be in the same directory as your `Dockerfile` and is intended to speed up the `docker build` command by excluding *at build time* some of the files that won't be used to build the docker image.

Comment: So, can I say the function of `.dockerignore` is help fast build?

Comment: yes. Anything that is not needed by your app should go in `.dockerignore`. A common line is `.git`, since many people version control their container images, and apps usually don't need all that data.